# Monte Carlo Method calculating pi

Tags: c++

I'm trying to calculate the pi using Monte Carlo Method. But I always get zero, I don't know why. 
Here's my code

```
   #include <tchar.h>
   #include <Windows.h>
   #include <omp.h>
   #include <iostream>
   #include<math.h>
   using namespace std;
   int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

       int N = 1000, n = 0;
       double x = 0, y = 0;
       double answer; 

       for (int i = 0; i < N; i++){
         x = (double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;
         y = (double)rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;

         if (((x*x) + (y*y)) < 1)
                ++n;
       }
       //cout << "n = " <<n << endl; 

       answer = n / N; 
       cout << answer*4.0 << endl;

       //system("pause");
  }
```

Comment: Both `n` and `N` are integers, so when you divide them, it's done as integer math. Since `n` is always less than or equal to `N`, the answer will always be 0. You then multiply by `4.0`, which produces a `double`, but by then it's too late -- 0 * 4.0 is still 0.

Answer (score 4):

Integer division in the `answer` calculation:

```
answer = n / N;
```

'nuff said.

**Edit 1:**
It's Friday, so I'll add some explanation.

The variables `n` and `N` are declared as integers.

The division takes precedence over any conversions or assignments.  The division is performed as two integers, then the *fractional* portion is truncated.  The remaining value is converted to `double` then assigned to the variable `answer`.

Please, please, don't differentiate identifiers by case.  The `n` and `N` should be different letters.  This helps the writer and reviewer refrain from typo defects.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Thanks.  Must be a Friday thing. :-)